# Equivalent code generation using FlaUI.UIA3 for accessing DevExpress DataGrid rows & columns in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress-wpf, dxgrid, flaui

I am using `FlaUI` to automate my `WPF` app. I have a `datagrid` control from `DevExpress`. I want to access any individual row and all the columns of that row and edit it using `FlaUI`. The DevExpress forum has the following sample available but this is for **UIA** library.How can I rewrite this using `FlaUI` libraries?

```
AutomationElement gridElem = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "datagrid"));  
GridPattern gridPattern = (GridPattern)gridElem.GetCurrentPattern(GridPattern.Pattern);  
int rowCount = gridPattern.Current.RowCount;  
 List<object> values = new List<object>();  
 for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {  
    AutomationElement item = gridPattern.GetItem(i, 0);  
    ValuePattern valuePattern = (ValuePattern)item.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern);  
    values.Add(valuePattern.Current.Value);
```

Very new to `FlaUI` & `automation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally with some help from `DevExpress` Support, I was able to achieve my intentions. Here is the piece of code that works well :)

```
public void CreateNewViewGrid(Grid grid)
        {
            var pattern = grid.Patterns.Grid;
            var rowCount = pattern.Pattern.RowCount;
            var colCount = pattern.Pattern.ColumnCount;
            var values = new List<object>();

            List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
            columnNames.Add("Vessel Id");
            columnNames.Add("Voyage Id");
            columnNames.Add("Load Date");
            columnNames.Add("Dis Date");
            columnNames.Add("Vessel Name");
            columnNames.Add("Status");

            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
            {

                var item = pattern.Pattern.GetItem(i, 0);
                var item2 = pattern.Pattern.GetItem(i, 1);
                var value = (item2.Patterns.Value.Pattern.Value).ToString();
                values.Add((value));

                foreach (var data in columnNames)
                {
                    if (value == data)
                    {

                        var itemStatus = item.AsGridCell();

                        itemStatus.Click();

                    }
                }

            }

            //Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", values));
            //return values;
        }
```

before this, finding element using `FlaUI is necessary`

Grid(reference from `FlaUI.Core.AutomationElements`) 
`private Grid grid=>windows.FindFirstDescendant(cf=>cf.ByAutomationID("dataGrid").AsGrid();`